# Multiple Table Search and show the result

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to fetch data from multiple tables in the Database and to Fetch data I tried using UNION ALL ... but I wasn't able to work on it.

```
$sqll = "SELECT * FROM msr_bills WHERE mobile='94825XXXX' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM hirisave_bills WHERE mobile='94825XXXX'";

$sql = mysqli_query($conn,$sqll);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['mobile'];
}
```

I am getting this error:

> The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: Please share more details. What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: What's the error. Try **mysqli** instead of mysql

Comment: Mysqli Error : The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns Iam Getting This Error –

Comment: Try mysqli_fetch_assoc and lets see

Comment: Still Its The Same !

Comment: Put a check on $sql, the result might be empty. Do tables has data?

Comment: Also try this **mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)**

Comment: Yes .. It Has the Data

Comment: Why not query the first table, and then the second one if they are completely independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to use `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
$sqll = "SELECT * FROM `msr_bills` mb LEFT JOIN `hirisave_bills` hb ON hb.`mobile` = mb.`mobile` WHERE mb.`mobile` = '94825XXXX'";
```

You have all columns from two tables or nulls from `hirisave_bills` if there is no such mobile number.

Comment: Mysqli Error : The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Iam Getting This Error

Answer (score 0):

you have diferent number of columns in your tables. try to select same number of columns

For example:

```
$sqll = "SELECT id, mobile FROM msr_bills WHERE mobile='94825XXXX' UNION ALL SELECT id, mobile FROM hirisave_bills WHERE mobile='94825XXXX'";
```